GoodWe hybrid inverter GW20K-ET
I just bought a GoodWe hybrid inverter GW20K-ET, unfortunately it only has one battery connection. On this connection the hybrid inverter can charge/discharge the battery with 50A. GoodWe offers Lynx F Plus+ batteries that can be connected in parallel. This battery can be charged/discharged with a maximum current of 25A.
The question is: if you connect two of these batteries in parallel, can you charge and discharge them with a total of 50A, or only with 25A? Does anyone have any information here?
Thanks for any insights!
Chrisgraham


can you charge and discharge them with a total of 50 A...

Yes.

...or only with 25 A?

Each battery will see about 25 A. The total in both batteries will be 50 A. But there is no guarantee that the current will be split equally between the two batteries. In the long term, though, that situation is self-correcting because the two batteries share the same voltage. After some time at no charging current, the two batteries will exchange charge and equalize.
